# sizzling sound with ALSA

Tags: 20.04, sound, alsa, soundcard

I was working on a Kdenlive project (snap version) on my PC when suddenly sound became sizzly and even after rebooting I can't get ride of it.

I already tried a lot of things as :

- Of course rebooting
- Purge, remove and then reinstall alsa audio
- Opened alsamixer to see if I could manage something on my soundcard (an USB scarlett one)
- Reloaded alsa and pulseaudio too using :

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

- Tried this command : `sudo systemctl status alsa-restore.service` and got that output :

```
  alsa-restore.service - Save/Restore Sound Card State
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/alsa-restore.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Wed 2022-03-23 08:33:18 CET; 12min ago
   Docs: man:alsactl(1)
Process: 1334 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/alsa (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 1335 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/alsactl -E HOME=/run/alsa -E XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/alsa/runtime restore (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Main PID: 1335 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

mars 23 08:33:18 marius-PC systemd[1]: Starting Save/Restore Sound Card State...
mars 23 08:33:18 marius-PC systemd[1]: Finished Save/Restore Sound Card State.
```

- Moreover, when I open up AlsaMixer and try to manage the sound directly on the soundcard, it says that this hardware (external usb soundcard) has no command and shows me nothing relative to this.

Do someone has a clue on what is going wrong and what could I do to get the sound back on my Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Comment: Hi Marius, I was running into similar issues and in my case, this appears to be related to the 5.13.0-37 kernel upgrade that got upgraded recently. I had crackling sound now and then which could be solved with pulseaudio -k, but in this case nothing helped. What did help was this workaround: https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=370408&p=2155041 - maybe it helps in your case?

Comment: Thanks a lot oliver ! I just tried this and now everything is fine !

Comment: @oliverguenther You may want to make that an answer so the OP can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just providing this as an answer since this helped both me and Marius according to your comment, and will be more visible than the comment.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=370408&p=2155041 fixed the issue. The gist of this link is this:

First, edit the global daemon file `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and set `default-sample-rate = 48000` (in my case, this was commented out)

Then, create a local daemon file `~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf` and also set the same command there `default-sample-rate = 48000`

Then kill the pulseaudi daemon

```
pulseaudio -k
```